# Tensorflow - Reusing model InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have issues using an exported tensorflow model. It doesn't allow me to evaluate the dataset I provided it with. If I run the evaluation in the same session as the training, there are no issues, however, that defeats the purpose of saving the model, if I have to retrain my model just to test with another dataset. The python file for generating the model is as such:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1024], name = "x")
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name = "y_")

#===Model===

#Train
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), name= "accuracy")
#Create Saver
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(40000):
  batch = shvn_data.nextbatch(100)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %f"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

#Save
saver.save(sess,'svhn_model1')
```

I saved input variables x and y_, to be fed through function 'accuracy', so that I can run accuracy.eval() to obtain the accuracy of prediction. I evaluated the dataset in batches of 100 images, then summed the final prediction. The python file to evaluate the model in another session is as such:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True          
sess = tf.Session(config = config) 

shvn_data = DataLoader()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('svhn_model1.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
#sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#Variables to use with model
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
y_ = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y_:0")
accuracy = graph.get_tensor_by_name("accuracy:0")
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)


img_whole = np.reshape(shvn_data.test_images,(-1,1024))
batch_whole = np.asarray(shvn_data.test_label.eval(), dtype = np.float32)

total_accuracy = 0
test_count = shvn_data.TEST_COUNT
batch_size = 100
steps = int(math.ceil(test_count/float(batch_size)))

for j in range(steps):
    start = j*batch_size
    if (j+1)*batch_size > shvn_data.TEST_COUNT:
        end = test_count
    else:
        end = (j+1)*batch_size

    img_batch = img_whole[start:end]
    label_batch = batch_whole[start:end]
    batch_accuracy = accuracy.eval(session = sess, feed_dict={ x: img_batch, y_: label_batch, keep_prob: 1.0}) #ISSUE LIES HERE

    print("Test batch %d:%d accuracy %g"%(start,end,batch_accuracy))
    total_accuracy += batch_accuracy

print ("Total Accuracy: %f" %(total_accuracy/steps))
```

The error is as follows.

```
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/ipython/start_kernel.py", line 227, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/ipython/start_kernel.py", line 223, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-33e4fce19d34>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/lwenyao/Desktop/Python/Import_Model.py', wdir='/home/lwenyao/Desktop/Python')
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 94, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/lwenyao/Desktop/Python/Import_Model.py", line 63, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('svhn_model1.meta')
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1595, in import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 499, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 308, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/lwenyao/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

As previously mentioned, evaluation has no issues if I run it in the same session when training the model. The only changes that I made were i added the argument `session = sess` each time I called .eval() when using the imported model. Sorry for the long post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it appears that the error was caused from attempting to create and use another `keep_prob` variable in the test script, after importing the model. I.e. I created `keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,)` in the training file. However,`accuracy.eval()` in the testing file was trying to look for `keep_prob` specifically from the model. I created another `keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,)` in testing file, thinking it would be the same, but it was not.

I modified my code in the training file by adding the label:
`keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob")`

and in my testing file, called for the model's variable:

```
#Variables to use with model
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
y_ = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y_:0")
keep_prob = graph.get_tensor_by_name("keep_prob:0")#Changed this
accuracy = graph.get_tensor_by_name("accuracy:0")
```

And now it works fine. My code is modified from **Deep MNIST for Experts** from tensorflow.